# Can you model a gemstone/diamond in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have been using advanced renderers like Vray to render gemstones (offline). I am working on a project to render them in real time using three.js

I am not a 3D expert and am wondering if its possible to implement some of the more advanced refraction, reflection shaders to simulate a sparkling/faceted gemstone, and if so where can I find the code to implement it

Comment: Additionally, if you have a 3d model with alot of facets but want to appeal to a low-end machine, you could simulate refraction by having a cubemap with various triangles of white, black, and your gemstone color.

Comment: To get around the limitations of WebGL, check out [Multi-pass Rendering](http://bkcore.com/blog/3d/webgl-three-js-animated-selective-glow.html) which would allow you to render both a Backface and Frontface reflective pass.

Answer (score 5):

For simulated refraction and reflection using cubemap shaders within `Three.js`, I would look at the source within this demo: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Bubble.html

[image]

For accurate Raytracing using Javascript (similar to VRay or other photon-lighting techniques): http://29a.ch/2010/6/2/realtime-raytracing-in-javascript

[image]